# Заменить несколько пробелов одним, а одиночные пробелы - спецсимволом

Tags: c#, строки, .net-core

Нужно программа, которая проверяет текстовые строки и заменяет последовательности пропусков одним пробелом, а там где один пробел - меняет его на символ %.

```
Console.Write("Enter string: ");
var text = Console.ReadLine();
string newword = null;
string textold = Regex.Replace(text, " {2,}", " ");
foreach (var el in textold)
{
    if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(el))
    {
        newword += '%'.ToString();
        continue;
    }
    newword += el.ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine($"New string: {newword}");
```

Comment: Если вы хотите готовую - то этот вопрос нетематичен для ru so (см. пункт про "поиск программ" в справке). Если вы хотите написать и вам нужна помощь, то вопрос нетематичен, т.к. тут не фриланс-биржа, а пока из вопроса не видно, что вы как-то сами пытались. Есть у вас свой код? С какими проблемами столкнулись, что неясно? Проголосовал за закрытие.

Comment: @AK, у меня есть наброски, вот только запутался в последовательности)

Comment: Пишите такие вещи сразу, а то очень быстро набирается пять голосов закрытие и вы ничего не успеете поправить (а никто и не сможет ответить на вопрос). Отозвал свой голос.

Comment: @AK, я вас понял, буду иметь в виду

Comment: там, где один пробел - это до или после предыдущего преобразования?

Comment: @vp_arth, это до замены много пробелов на один

Answer (score 4):

А почему бы сначала одиночные пробелы не заменить %, а потом множественные пробелы заменить одним

```
   Console.Write("Enter string: ");
   var text = Console.ReadLine();

   text = Regex.Replace(text, "\\b(\\s{1})\\b", "%");
   text = Regex.Replace(text, " {2,}", " ");

   Console.WriteLine($"New string: {text}");
```

Comment: Имху, это самый простой и изящный вариант, без использования конечных автоматов и регулярок.

Answer (score 3):

Логика может быть примерно такой:

```
count = 0;
foreach (var el in text)    {
     if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(el)) 
         count++;  
     else {
        if (count==1)
           newword += "%";
        if (count>1)
           newword += " ";
        newword += el.ToString();
        count = 0;
     }
 }
```

С использованием `StringBuilder` ([ideone](https://ideone.com/yeqL6B)). Если пробелы в конце нужно обработать таким же образом, то строчки с `if (count` после цикла ещё раз добавить.

```
Console.Write("Enter string: ");
var text = Console.ReadLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("", text.Length);
int count = 0;
foreach (var el in text)    {
     if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(el)) 
         count++;  
     else {
        if (count==1)
           sb.Append('%',1);
        if (count>1)
           sb.Append(' ',1);
        sb.Append(el,1);
        count = 0;
     }
 }
Console.WriteLine($"New string: {sb.ToString()}");
```

Comment: Сюда прямо напрашивается StringBuilder и тогда это будет лучший вариант (не по наглядности, ответ Pavel Popov в этом плане мне кажется лучше) по части быстродействия и использования ресурсов.

Comment: @A K Угу, добавил.

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант что пришел в голову -
Запарсить все строки в массив и с помощью  string.replace заменить

```
for(int i=0; i<NeedReplace.Length;i++)
{
NeedReplace[i].Replace(' ', '%');
}
```

Как-то так.

Comment: да у меня тоже такой вариант был, но оно получается все пробелы заменит на этот знак, а тут задача чуть другая, нужно одиночные пробелы заменить на %, а там где есть посаледовательность проблелов, то там нужно просто оставить один пробел

Comment: Тогда используй поиск с помощью Regex